# php echo a list of numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a list of numbers, one per line, and instead it keeps giving errors or returning a single line of numbers like 12345678910112

```
   <?php

foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo "<br />\r\n" $number;

}
?>
```

Comment: you are missing a dot between "<br/>\n\n" and $number

Comment: _"and instead it keeps giving errors"_ What errors?

Comment: Start with the PHP documentation, including the errors that it gives you. Otherwise, you will be posting a lot of questions on StackOverflow!

Comment: You missing dot `.` or coma `,`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php .

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo "<br />\r\n".$number;

}
?>
```

You need to concatenate strings using a DOT ...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a dot here:

```
echo "<br />\r\n" $number;
```

It should be this:

```
echo "<br />\r\n" . $number;
```

You can read more about the concatenation operator in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i<12; $i++){
    echo $i . "<br \>";
}

?>
```

Use `for` instead for `foreach`?
I think `foreach` is more suitable for arrays, but just for looping numbers I recommend using `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error - you missed dot to concat strings.

```
echo "<br />\r\n" . $number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate `"<br />\r\n"` and `$number` using the [concatenation operator (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
foreach(range(0, 12) as $number) {
  echo "<br />\r\n" . $number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the dot

```
echo "<br />\r\n" . $number;
```

or

```
echo "<br />\r\n $number";
```